# Unable to finish Samba Setup - Kubuntu 21.10

Tags: networking, kubuntu, samba, file-sharing

I've been attemping to set up a Samba share from my Linux host to my Win10VM. I'm trying to get away from using Windows, but still need some Windows-only software for work. I've chosent to go the VM route rather than dual boot because I don't want to have to restart my computer every time I need to do something. That gets real old REAL fast.

So I want to be able to share files from a tertiary internal hard drive on my laptop with the Win10VM. I have 3 internal hard drives on my computer

1. Windows (don't want to use anymore) - want to remove drive and replace with more storage
2. Linux - Kubuntu 21.10
3. Storage drive where work files are

I need to access drive 3 from both Linux *and* the Win10VM.

I have a Win10VM set up with Virt-manager with all of the necessary programs installed. Currently I simply CANNOT get Samba configured to the point where I can share files. I started following the tutorial at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#1-overview - and I get to step 4 and get this error:

```
[system]:~$ sudo smbpasswd -a username
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Failed to add entry for user username.
```

And I just.... **cannot** figure out how to move past this. It's incredibly frustrating.

I've even *completely* removed Samba from my system and reinstalling it and I recieve the same error. And yes I did reboot my system in between the uninstall and reinstall just to be safe. And I used the purge command when I uninstalled as well.

If anyone could give me a hand on this I'd really appreciate it. Most of what I've found online is stuff where the linux host is a server just sitting in a closet somewhere, but that's not what I'm doing. I've got a laptop with Kubuntu and a Win10VM and I need them both to have access to the same files.

Thanks

**System info:**

Operating System: Kubuntu 21.10

KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.5

KDE Frameworks Version: 5.86.0

Qt Version: 5.15.2

Kernel Version: 5.13.0-39-generic (64-bit)

Graphics Platform: X11

Processors: 16 × Intel® Core™ i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz

Memory: 31.2 GiB of RAM

Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: Are you literally typing 'sudo smbpasswd -a username' ? If so, you are supposed to replace 'username' with your users name i.e. what the user logins in as.

Comment: @RowlandPenny this is going to sound really stupid.... but yes. I was just doing a copy paste. Because the REST of the instrctions were also copy/paste. And now I feel like a dumbass.